# Git merge states "Already up to date", commits are in master but changes were essentially overwritten on the very next commit

Tags: git, github, git-merge

This is likely a duplicate but I can't find anything definitive for this specific issue. So a couple weeks ago I'm pretty certain that I merged a branch into our master branch, the commits are there in masters history but there is no merge message stating the branch was merged. In the history when viewing my commits the changes are clearly there but when viewing the project files on the very next commit the changes are not present. Trying to git merge again of course errors and says "Already up to date" which yes technically it is.

What is the best way to get these changes into the master branch? I suppose I could create a new branch with the same changes then merge that branch into master...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All commits—*including* merge commits—are full and complete snapshots of all files.  So, if someone decided, for whatever reason, to change the files that you changed, so as to undo your changes, and committed that *in any form* (merge or regular commit), that new snapshot has the files the way *they* arranged them.

We can't see your repository so it's hard to guess exactly who did what, how.

(Be aware that various Git viewers "flatten" what is inherently a tangled history when there are merges, and may view commits out of order.  Add `--graph` to your `git log` command, if you are using `git log` to view commits, to force `git log` to display the commits in commit-graph order, and to draw a crude ASCII graph of the commits' relationships.)

> What is the best way to get these changes into the master branch?

*Best* is a matter of opinion, but for *easy*, you can always use `git cherry-pick`.

The way `git cherry-pick` works is that you give it a name—such as a raw hash ID—for a commit.<sup>1</sup>  Git then compares that commit with its parent (singular).  This comparison between "before" and "after" snapshots shows what *changed* between the two snapshots, so Git can now re-apply those same changes to whatever commit you've just checked out.

Hence:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <hash>
```

works to copy the effect of any given ordinary commit.

If your merge brought in the effect of some large number of commits, though, you might want to `git cherry-pick` the entire merge.  The immediate stumbling block is that a merge commit has *more than one parent*.  On its own, `git cherry-pick` just throws its metaphorical hands in the air and gives up: it does not know which parent to use, when comparing parent to child to see "what happened in this commit".

As a rule, though, the right parent to use is almost always parent #1.  If that *is* the right parent, you just tell that to `git cherry-pick` using its `-m` option:

```
git cherry-pick -m 1 <hash>
```

To tell whether parent #1 is the right commit to use, you can do a comparison yourself between parent #1 and the given commit:

```
git diff <hash>^1 <hash>
```

The `^1` suffix tells Git: *move from this commit to its first parent*.  (See footnote 1 and the gitrevisions documentation, again.)  The `diff` therefore compares the snapshot in parent #1 to the snapshot in *`hash`*.  The result of that comparison is the set of changes that `git cherry-pick` will try to copy.

If parent #1 is the wrong parent, try each of the remaining parents in turn.  Since most merges only have two parents, that just leaves parent #2:

```
git diff <hash>^2 <hash>
```

This will show what the difference is between the *second* parent and the given commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Any name will do; see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for a very long list of ways to name commits.  The "true name", as it were, is the raw hash ID though: that one always works, and always names that one specific commit.  The only drawback to using this is that the name is impossible to remember and hard to type, but it's usually easy to cut and paste the hash ID from `git log` output, for instance.

Comment: Thank you for the very verbose answer! I went ahead and ran git cherry-pick <commit> on the master branch, merged the files, committed and I believe that I have the desired effect. Thank you!